# Objective Sharpie Invalid Image when binding Swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to bind a Swift library to my Xamarin project. When following this [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough) I ran into an issue using the objective sharpie tool.

sharpie -v

3.5.45-0e5ab58b

Here is the issue I receive from sharpie :

```
Binding...
System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid Image
File name: '/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.iOS.dll'
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(string,bool,System.Threading.StackCrawlMark&)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom (System.String assemblyFile) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:367 
  at Sharpie.Bind.Massagers.XamarinApiMappingMassager.Initialize () [0x0002c] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/Sharpie.Bind/Massagers/XamarinApiMappingMassager.cs:50 
  [write] ApiDefinitions.cs
  [write] StructsAndEnums.cs

Binding Analysis:
  Automated binding is complete, but there are a few APIs which have been flagged with [Verify] attributes. While the entire binding should be audited for best API design practices, look more closely at APIs with the
  following Verify attribute hints:

  ConstantsInterfaceAssociation (1 instance):
    There's no foolproof way to determine with which Objective-C interface an extern variable declaration may be associated. Instances of these are bound as [Field] properties in a partial interface into a nearby
    concrete interface to produce a more intuitive API, possibly eliminating the 'Constants' interface altogether.

  Once you have verified a Verify attribute, you should remove it from the binding source code. The presence of Verify attributes intentionally cause build failures.
  
  For more information about the Verify attribute hints above, consult the Objective Sharpie documentation by running 'sharpie docs' or visiting the following URL:

    http://xmn.io/sharpie-docs

Done
```

I have attempted to use a couple different swift libraries and all of them produce the same error.

I have noticed [similar issues](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/14168) and was wondering if anyone has been able to solve this problem?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve are you referring to the Bind Analysis test output? If so those are just warning messages for manual processing. They don't impact the creation of the ApiDefinitions.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs files as I understand it. The issue I am asking for assistance with is Invalid Image issue found above theBind Analysis section.

Comment: my bad.  It wasn’t clear to me that it didn’t generate ApiDefinitions.cs. I had thought that the result was an api class that needed some edits. If you try a very simple test case, does it work? If so,  and you have access to source, try marking obj c original with fewer public members. Then add any missing ones to .cs.

Comment: No problem, I am using a very simple custom made swift library. I have also tried using the same SDKs used in a couple tutorials. All of them produced this issue. This is an example of a tutorial I tried: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough.

Comment: try  "sharpie bind -output Binding --namespace=PodName --sdk=iphoneos15.0 ./PodName/PodName.h -v"

 the ./ that should limit the scope where sharpie and clang look for things IIRC.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT I am still receiving the `System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid Image` error. Do you believe this error could be caused by other files?

Comment: how about try to wirte a simple swift library without image and test it with binding?